# OpenGl Shader Program Linking error with uncertain reason

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to make a framework that uses OpenGL.

Yet, having problem to reload shader program.

[image: Succeeds to link]

This is what I have right now.

I load and compile a vertex shader and a fragment shader(both contain main).

Than I link a program with them.

At first, it has no problem. No matter how much time I refresh shaders.
(If I press Refresh Shader, the application creates new shader, program resource and replaces original ones with them)

Than, if I load a mesh and preform some drawing calls(using VBO), This time Refresh Shader Fails with following message.

[image: Fails to link]

I have no idea how my draw calls or VBO function calls could possibly be related to Shader Linking...

I'm not even sure if that is the exact reason or not.

Shader class:

```
  class Shader : public Named
  {

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // --------------- Defs ----------------------------------
  public:
    typedef void (*ErrFunc)( Shader* pShader, const char* const errMsg );



    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // --------------- Funcs ---------------------------------
  public:

    //
    // Shader Controls
    //
    // pre: source is string contains source
    Shader( const std::string& name, GLenum type);

    ~Shader( void );

    // pre: file to loast source. Give nullptr to load from lastly loaded file
    void ShaderSourceFromFile( const char* file );

    void ShaderSource( const std::string& source );

    void Compile( void );

    void AttachTo( GLuint program );

    void DetachFrom( GLuint program );

    GLuint GetId( void );

    void SetId( GLuint shaderId );

    GLint GetType( void );

    GLint GetCompileStatus( void );

    const char* const GetShaderInfoLog( void );


    //
    // Err Control
    //
  public:

    void Error ( const char* pErrMsg );

    static ErrFunc SetErrFunc( ErrFunc fpNewErrFunc );


    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // ----------- Vars --------------------------------------
  private:
    // id of the shader
    GLuint  _shaderId;

    // type of the shader
    GLenum  _type;

    // error func
    static ErrFunc s_fpErrFunc;





  }; // class Shader

  //
  // Shader
  //

  Shader::ErrFunc Shader::s_fpErrFunc = nullptr;


  Shader::Shader( const std::string& name, GLenum type) :
    Named(name),
    _shaderId(GL_INVALID_RESOURCE_ID),
    _type(type)
  {
    // Create shader
    GLint id = glCreateShader(type);

    // Failed to create shader?
    if ( id == GL_INVALID_RESOURCE_ID )
      Error("(Shader::Shader) Failed to create shader resource");

    // Set shader id
    SetId(id);

  }

  Shader::~Shader( void )
  {
    // Delete shader
    glDeleteShader(GetId());

    // Error Check
    if( glGetError() == GL_INVALID_VALUE )
      Error("(Shader::~Shader) given id to delete was not shader");
  }

  void Shader::Compile( void )
  {
    // Compile shader
    glCompileShader(_shaderId);

    switch( glGetError() )
    {
    case GL_NO_ERROR:break;
    case GL_INVALID_VALUE:     Error("shader is not a value generated by OpenGL.");break;
    case GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Error("shader is not a shader object.");break;
    default:Error("Unkown Error");
    }
    // ErrorCheck
    if( GetCompileStatus() == GL_FALSE )
      Error("(Shader::Compile) Compilation Failed.");

  }

  void Shader::ShaderSourceFromFile( const char* file  )
  {
      ShaderSource(ReadEntireFile(file));
  }
  // pre: source is string contains source
  void Shader::ShaderSource( const std::string& source )
  {
    const GLchar* pSource = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource( GetId(),  // shader id
                    1,        // count of source. only one at a time at the moment
                    &pSource, // buffer that source is stored
                    nullptr); // length is not specified, yet null terminated
    switch( glGetError() )
    {
    case GL_NO_ERROR:
      break;
    case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
      Error("invalid shader or bufsize is less than 0");
      break;
    case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:  
      Error("shader is not a shader object."); 
      break;
    default:
      Error("Unkown Error");
      break;
    }
  }
  void Shader::AttachTo( GLuint program )
  {
    glAttachShader(program, GetId());

    if( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
      Error("(Shader::AttachTo) Error Happend Performing glAttachShader");
    }
  }

  void Shader::DetachFrom( GLuint program )
  {
    glDetachShader(program, GetId());

    switch( glGetError() )
    {
    case GL_NO_ERROR:
      break;
    case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
      Error("(Shader::DetachFrom)either program or shader is a value that was not generated by OpenGL.");
      break;
    case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
      Error("(Shader::DetachFrom)program is not a program object. or "
      "shader is not a shader object. or "
      "shader is not attached to program.");
      break;
    default:
      Error("(Shader::DetachFrom)Unkown Error");
        break;
    }
  }

  GLuint Shader::GetId( void )
  {
    return _shaderId;
  }

  void Shader::SetId( GLuint shaderId )
  {
    _shaderId = shaderId;
  }

  GLint Shader::GetType( void )
  {
    return _type;
  }

  void Shader::Error ( const char* pErrMsg )
  {
    if( s_fpErrFunc )
      s_fpErrFunc(this, pErrMsg);
  }

  Shader::ErrFunc Shader::SetErrFunc( ErrFunc fpNewErrFunc )
  {
    ErrFunc prev = s_fpErrFunc;
    s_fpErrFunc = fpNewErrFunc;
    return prev;
  }

  GLint Shader::GetCompileStatus( void )
  {
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(GetId(), GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    GLint err = glGetError();
    switch( err )
    {
    case GL_NO_ERROR:
      break;
    case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
      Error("(Shader::GetCompileStatus) Invalid Enum passed to glGetShaderiv");
      break;
    case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
      Error("(Shader::GetCompileStatus) Invalid Shader id passed to glGetShaderiv");
      break;
    case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
      Error("(Shader::GetCompileStatus) Invalid Shader id or shader does not support");
      break;
    default:
      Error("(Shader::GetCompileStatus) Unkown Error");
      break;

    }
    return status;
  }
  const char* const Shader::GetShaderInfoLog( void )
  {
    static const unsigned s_bufSize = 0x1000;
    static GLchar s_buf[s_bufSize] = {0};

    // Get InfoLog
    glGetShaderInfoLog(GetId(), s_bufSize, nullptr, s_buf);

    // Error Check
    if( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR )
      Error("(Shader::GetCompileStatus) There was Error performing glGetShaderInfoLog");

    // return buffer
    return s_buf;
  }
```

Refreshing Function:

```
 void GLShaderManager::Refresh( void )
  {



  // Gets current shader
  Shader* pVertexPrev = _shaderMap["Vertex"];
  Shader* pFragPrev = _shaderMap["Fragment"];


  // Delete them(glDeleteShader call is included)
  if( pVertexPrev && pFragPrev )
  {
    delete pVertexPrev;
    delete pFragPrev;
  }


  // Loads shader
  LoadShader("Vertex", GL_VERTEX_SHADER, s_vertexFile);
  LoadShader("Fragment", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, s_fragmentFile);

  // Delete Current Program
  glDeleteProgram(_program);

  // Create new Program
  GLuint newProgram = glCreateProgram();
  _program = newProgram;

  // Attach Shaders
  UseShader("Vertex");
  UseShader("Fragment");

  // Linking
  glLinkProgram(_program);
  const unsigned bufSize = 0x1000;
  char buf[bufSize] = { '\0' };
  GLint status = 0;
  glGetProgramiv(_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
  if( status )
    Gui::Get().Output("Shader program linked successfully.");
  glGetProgramInfoLog(_program, bufSize, nullptr, buf);
  Gui::Get().Output(buf);


  s_uniformErrHistory.clear();
}

void GLShaderManager::LoadShader( const std::string& name, GLenum type, const std::string& sourceFile )
    {
      Shader* pShader = _shaderMap[name] = new Shader(name, type);
      if( pShader )
      {
        pShader->ShaderSourceFromFile(sourceFile.c_str());
        pShader->Compile();
        if( pShader->GetCompileStatus() )
          Gui::Get().Output( (pShader->GetName() + " shader successfully compiled.").c_str());
        Gui::Get().Output(pShader->GetShaderInfoLog());
      }
    }
    void GLShaderManager::UseShader( const std::string& name )
    {
      Shader* pShader = _shaderMap[name];
      if( pShader )
      {
          pShader->AttachTo(_program);
      }
    }
```

Comment: can we see the shader code?

Comment: Could you please show the actual shader code you're using?

Comment: On a hunch, what happens if you print the character array that is supposed to be your shader to stdout before passing it to GL? Believe it or not, you can compile empty strings... and of course, they do not generate any "object code."